# How to display tree sturcture recursively in laravel blade?

Tags: arrays, laravel, recursion

I have an array output is tree like structure like this:

[image]

Here, I have a database table with parent child relationship like:

```
public function up()
{
     Schema::create('trees', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->increments('id');
         $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
         $table->string('name');
         $table->integer('has_child');
         $table->integer('depth');
         $table->timestamps();
         $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('trees')->onDelete('cascade');
    }
}
```

Here,

Depth defines depth from root in the tree, `parent_id` refers to parent in same table and `has_child` defines existance of child. For the leaf, `has_child` is zero and for the top parent_id is null.

The depth can be any value up to 5.
In above case there is only 2 for test purpose.

Here is my sample database record:

[image]

I have got the above tree structure recursively in controller as:

```
    public function getChilds($d){
        $tree = array();
        $children = array();
        $tree['parent'] = $d->toArray();
        if($d->has_child==1){
            $data = Tree::where('parent_id',$d->id)->get();
            foreach ($data as $d) {
                $first = $this->getChilds($d);
                array_push($children, $first);
            }
        }
        $tree['children'] = $children;
        return $tree;
    }

    public function getTree(){
        $tree = array();
        $data = Tree::where('parent_id',null)->get();
        foreach ($data as $d) {
            $first = $this->getChilds($d);
            array_push($tree, $first);
        }
        return view('tree',compact('tree'));
    }
```

Now,

I want to display this data in tree like strucure. But, because of variable depth, I can't figure out a depth up to which I should go.

Is there any way to display this structure recursively in laravel blade ?

Expected output is something like this:

```
One0

    One0Two0

        One0Two0Three0

        One0Two0Three1

    One0Two1

        One0Two1Three0

        One0Two1Three1

    One0Two2

        One0Two2Three0

        One0Two2Three1
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you laravel-nestedset package which will make your life really easy please follow the package documentation to create your table structure, retrieving, saving and updating recursive data will be really easy. here is package link.

https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: I've already take a moment to view this but i've not understand the use of those package in my problem

Comment: I have used this but I still don't know how to pass the tree structure to the view...

Comment: What you are trying to do creating menu or something else?